# Passing parameter from Spring controller to Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jsp, spring-mvc, servlets

I have the following scenario:

1) I have an index.jsp with a form in it

2) On submit, the information is submited to a spring controller which gets the values from the form as parameters

3) A new page, newpage.jsp is returned. Based on the parameters submited in the previous page i need to call an an angular function from an angular controller.

My idea was that, once the the form is submited, get parameters in the spring controller and add them to the request. Using them, I create new containers in the newpage.jsp with attributes coresponding to each parameter from request and then get elements using javascript and get attributes values in order to make my function call.

Anyway, this solution doesn't look very good to me, so is there any way to get parameters from the request to use them in angular ?

Sorry for not posting any code, but I hope i explained the situation good enough.

Comment: _"then get elements"_ Which elements? If you need JavaScript then write JavaScript.

Comment: elements ..I was reffering to new created containers, to get the parameter values I was talking about

Comment: Do you create them anyway or just for the parameters?

Comment: just for the parameters. it is my solution to pass the parameters from the response  to javascript. i couldn't find any other way